# Is something wrong with this piece of PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this line of PHP code? I am trying to insert values in a database.

```
<?php

// Some database detail
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'mywebsite';
$con;



 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (Name, Password) VALUES ('Daniel', 'abc123')");

 // Making connection
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error());


?>
```

**THE ERROR:**

> Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\database.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\database.php on line 13

Comment: I see the problem. You're storing passwords in plain text instead of [hashing them](http://php.net/password_hash).

Comment: put query query below connection

Comment: @user41510 Where you are putting the $con??

Comment: most databases don't allow a blank password, especially for root.

Comment: use connection before insert query..what is the error that you are getting

Comment: @BrianAnderson MySQL lets you do that. Actually you can do it in MSSSQL too, just not during install.

Answer (score 0):

webserver reads PHP code line by line from the top of the page.

it displays **Undefined variable** error on the variable because you use it before you define `$con`.
so when the webserver reach *line 13*, it doesn't know what is variable `$con` and then it throws the error.

My suggestion is the same with the others.
put the

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die(mysqli_error());
```

above this

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (Name, Password) VALUES ('Daniel', 'abc123')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this ..This will help you

```
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'mywebsite';

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysqli_error());
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("mywebsite", $con);

$check= mysqli_query("INSERT INTO members (Name, Password) VALUES ('Daniel', 'abc123')");

if($check)
 echo "inserted";
else
 echo "not inserted";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code:

You just need to connect to database before INSERT .

```
<?php

// Some database detail
$host = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'mywebsite';

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));



 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO members (Name, Password) VALUES ('Daniel', 'abc123')");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a query into the database before making a connection to it. Swith lines 13 and 11.